# jQuery function on resize and on load without copy/pasting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of jQuery that checks the width of the browser on load, and runs accordingly. But to make sure the `div` keeps the right size when the browser-width is changed, I have placed the same piece of code in `$(window).resize(function() {..});`.

This seems very weird and unnecessary, so I'm wondering how I can place the code only once and have it run on both `.resize` and on load.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
    $('.banner_image').show();
    $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
    $('.banner .span12 img').hide();            
}
else {
    $('.banner_image').hide();
    $('.banner .span12 img').show();
}

$(window).resize(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
        $('.banner_image').show();
        $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
        $('.banner .span12 img').hide();                
    }
    else {
        $('.banner_image').hide();
        $('.banner .span12 img').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the event after binding the event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
    $('.banner_image').show();
    $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
    $('.banner .span12 img').hide();                
}
else {
    $('.banner_image').hide();
    $('.banner .span12 img').show();
}).resize();//resize to trigger on load
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hd3ucb65)**

Comment: Yes, exactly this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just store the function in a variable and execute it everytime you want to:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   wFunc();
});    

$(window).resize(function() {
   wFunc();
});   

var wFunc = function() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   if(windowWidth > 768 && windowWidth < 1223){
    $('.banner_image').show();
    $('.banner_image').height($('.banner .span3').height());
    $('.banner .span12 img').hide();            
   }
   else {
    $('.banner_image').hide();
    $('.banner .span12 img').show();
   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, because I think it's much nicer to read and change later on.